# For Laravel, how to return a response to client in a inner function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, response

I'm building an API using laravel, the issue is when the client requests my API by calling `create()` function, and the `create()` function will call a `getValidatedData()` function which I want to return validation errors to the client if validation fails or return the validated data to insert database if validation passes, my `getValidatedData` function is like below so far:

```
protected function getValidatedData(array $data)
{
    // don't format this class since the rule:in should avoid space
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'ID' => 'required',
        'weight' => 'required',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        exit(Response::make(['message' => 'validation fails', 'errors' => $validator->errors()]));
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I don't think `exit()` is a good way to return the errors message to clients. Are there any other ways I can return the laravel response to clients directly in an inner function? Use throwing Exception?

Answer (score 12):

This was what worked for me in Laravel 5.4

```
protected function innerFunction()
{
    $params = [
        'error' => 'inner_error_code',
        'error_description' => 'inner error full description'
    ];
    response()->json($params, 503)->send();
}
```

Comment: Work for me in 5.5, but not stopped the execution. I fixed adding "exit;" after the response.

Comment: 2 things this approach has tripped me up on: 1.Breaks PHP Unit HTTP tests,

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is using `send` method, so you can use:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    Response::make(['message' => 'validation fails', 'errors' => $validator->errors()])->send();
}
```

but be aware this is not the best solution, better would be for example throwing exception with those data and adding handling it in `Handler` class.

**EDIT**

As sample of usage:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->xxx();
}

protected function xxx()
{
    \Response::make(['message' => 'validation fails', 'errors' => ['b']])->send();
    dd('xxx');
}
```

assuming that `index` method is method in controller you will get as response json and `dd('xxx');` won't be executed

Comment: send() doesn't work cause I want script ends and return error messages to the client if validation fails.  I don't the code after send()  be executed . Thx for the editing btw

Comment: @mark Send will cause that this response will be imediatelly sent and the code after this won't be executed

Comment: I look into Laravel api , there is no send method in Class Response, but I got a method called  throwResponse() which works it out. Thx

Comment: @mark Look at my edit. There is such method but it's not directly in Response class but in parent class of Response class and it works as showed in my edited answer

Comment: this worked really well for me. I have a check validation method on a trait that gets used by my main Api controller, and it was nice to be able to call that, pass request and validation rules and let it handle returning the errors instead of doing that in every method. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if you call your controller in tests (http tests), it will just print the output to the screen instead of sending it to the test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
 public static function Validate($request ,$rolse)
{
    // validation data
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rolse);

    $errors = $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray();
    $first_error = array_key_first($errors);
    if (count($errors) > 0)
        return  'invalid input params , ' . $errors[$first_error][0];

    return false;

}
```

in controller :

```
   $validate = ValidationHelper::Validate($request,
        ['title' => 'required']);

    if ($validate)
         return response()->json(['message' =>'validation fails' , 'error'=> $validate], 403);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but it might still help someone:
I tried returning a response from my inner function like this as suggested by the other answers:

```
response()->json([
  'error' => true,
  'error_message' => 'Error Message',
], 404)->send();
exit;
```

But I stumbled upon problems with CORS whenever I got responses back like this, because the CORS headers were missing.
I'm now using the `throwResponse` method and it seems to be working without issues.

```
response()->json([
  'error' => true,
  'error_message' => 'Error Message',
], 404)->throwResponse();
```